# Pydoop call not working when inside Celery task

Tags: python, hadoop, celery

I've set up two files for a project using [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and [Pydoop](https://crs4.github.io/pydoop/), **tasks.py** and **HDFSStorage.py**

```
# tasks.py

from celery import Celery
from celery import shared_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from HDFSStorage import HDFSStorage

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
fs = HDFSStorage()
print fs.exists("/myfile.txt")

@shared_task
def add(x,y):
    logger.info('Adding {0} + {1}'.format(x, y))
    logger.info('Checking if file exists')
    fs.exists("/myfile.txt")
    logger.info('Done checking if file exists')
    return x+y
```

---

```
# HDFSStorage.py

import pydoop
from pydoop.hdfs import hdfs

class HDFSStorage():
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = hdfs(host="master", port=54310, user="oskar")

    def exists(self, name):
        return self.client.exists(name)
```

---

Running Celery starts with the `fs.exists()` call outside the task and outputs `True` as expected.

```
$ celery -A tasks worker -l info
True
[2016-06-08 15:54:15,298: WARNING/MainProcess] /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ce
lery/apps/worker.py:161: CDeprecationWarning:
Starting from version 3.2 Celery will refuse to accept pickle by default.

The pickle serializer is a security concern as it may give attackers
the ability to execute any command.  It's important to secure
your broker from unauthorized access when using pickle, so we think
that enabling pickle should require a deliberate action and not be
the default choice.

If you depend on pickle then you should set a setting to disable this
warning and to be sure that everything will continue working
when you upgrade to Celery 3.2::

    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']

You must only enable the serializers that you will actually use.


  warnings.warn(CDeprecationWarning(W_PICKLE_DEPRECATED))

 -------------- celery@master v3.1.23 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.19.0-32-generic-x86_64-with-LinuxMint-17.3-rosa
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x7f510d3162d0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . tasks.add

[2016-06-08 15:54:15,371: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672/
/
[2016-06-08 15:54:15,382: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2016-06-08 15:54:16,395: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2016-06-08 15:54:16,412: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@master ready.
[2016-06-08 15:54:19,736: INFO/MainProcess] Events of group {task} enabled by remote.
```

---

However, running the task which has the same `fs.exists()` call gets stuck for some unknown reason.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tasks import add
True
>>> print add.delay(5,4).get()
```

---

```
[2016-06-08 15:54:32,833: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.add[a50409a8-f82d-4376-
ace2-442a09c9ed4f]
[2016-06-08 15:54:32,834: INFO/Worker-2] tasks.add[a50409a8-f82d-4376-ace2-442a09c9ed4f]
: Adding 5 + 3
[2016-06-08 15:54:32,834: INFO/Worker-2] tasks.add[a50409a8-f82d-4376-ace2-442a09c9ed4f]
: Checking if file exists
```

---

Removing the `fs.exists()` call in the task makes the task finish correctly.

What am I doing wrong? What makes Celery to not work with Pydoop?

Answer (score 2):

The HDFSStorage instance must be created inside the task

```
# tasks.py

from celery import Celery
from celery import shared_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from HDFSStorage import HDFSStorage

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@shared_task
def add(x,y):
    fs = HDFSStorage()
    logger.info('Adding {0} + {1}'.format(x, y))
    logger.info('Checking if file exists')
    fs.exists("/myfile.txt")
    logger.info('Done checking if file exists')
    return x+y
```